# I need to create a list of monthly values based upon a data range and value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data table with a monthly revenue value and a date range this applies to.  I need to create a monthly revenue value (a row by month) based upon this date range.  What is the best way to do this in Excel

I have not been able to get a formula to work. Happy to use Macro or VBA to loop through each row and create necessary data in another worksheet but have not been able to figure out how to create this code.

In this case, for first row in attached image, I need to create a row for each month between 12/2019 and 5/2021 with a revenue value of $1875 for each month.  And I need to repeat this for every row in the table.

| DtFrom | DtTo | dMonthlyAmt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2020 | 12/31/2022 | $1000.00 |
| 1/1/2019 | 7/31/2024 | 1750.00 |
| 3/1/2022 | 6/30/2024 | 2250.00 |

What I need to create in the case of the first row is a row for each month from 1/1/2020 to 12/31/2022 with a value of 1000.00.

Any assistance that can be offered would be appreciated - I need to try to complete this today.

Comment: I can't access your link. Can you post a table into the body of your question with sufficient sample data to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 0):

There are certainly many ways to accomplish this. Possibly an array formula in a cell or maybe a Power Query. I am most familiar with VBA so consider following options.

```
Sub BuildRows()
Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const adCmdText = &H1

Dim cn As Object, rs As Object
Dim r As Integer, dt As Date
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";HDR=Yes';"
rs.Open "Select DtFrom, DtTo, dMonthlyAmt FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE NOT DtFrom IS NULL", cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

r = 2

Do While Not rs.EOF
    dt = rs!DtFrom
    Do While dt < rs!DtTo
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 6) = dt
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 7) = rs!dMonthlyAmt
        dt = DateAdd("m", 1, dt)
        r = r + 1
    Loop
    If Not rs.EOF Then rs.MoveNext
Loop
End Sub
```

Instead of opening and looping a recordset, could loop worksheet rows and cells.

```
Sub BuildRows()
Dim rS As Integer, rD As Integer, dt As Date

rS = 2
rD = 2
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
Do While Not IsEmpty(.Cells(rS, 1))
    dt = CDate(.Cells(rS, 1))
    Do While dt < .Cells(rS, 2)
        .Cells(rD, 6) = dt
        .Cells(rD, 7) = .Cells(rS, 3)
        dt = DateAdd("m", 1, dt)
        rD = rD + 1
    Loop
    rS = rS + 1
Loop
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I will let you know how I make out later this afternoon